# Editable Column not working in Kartik Expand Row Grid

Tags: gridview, yii, kartik-v

Updated data not getting posted. I'm using kartik advanced grid and kartik editable.

editableAjaxError not returning any errors.  The actual column updates but it doesn't seem to submit form data (the editable popup data)

Update: Added indexAction, and two grids. Main grid and exandrow grid template.

actionIndex

```
public function actionIndex()
    {

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')){
            // return empty json object for now
            echo Json::encode(['output' => '', 'message' => Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')]);
            return;
        }

        $searchModel = new \common\models\CustomerMasterSearch();
        $queryParams = array_merge(array(),Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
        if(isset(Yii::$app->request->queryParams['CustomerMasterSearch']))           
        {

            // some code here

        }  
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

views/index.php

```
echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'pjax' => true,
        'columns' => [
            //['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
                'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column){
                    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
                },
                'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column){

                    $searchModel = new BrandBudgetSearch();
                    $searchModel->customerid = $model->customerid;

                    $queryParams = array_merge(array(),Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());
                    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($queryParams);

                    return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_brandbudget', [
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    ]);
                }
            ],
```

views/_brandbudget.php

```
echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'pjax'=>true,
            'columns' => [
                [
                    'attribute' => 'brand_name',
                    'value' => function($model,$key,$idx,$col){
                            return $model['brand_name'];
                        },
                ],
                [
                    'class'=>'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
                    'value' => function($model,$row){
                            //return $model->brand_name;
                            return $model->getMonthBudget(new DateTime('2017-01'), [11311])['budget_net']; // TODO - Testingv
                        },
                    'editableOptions' => [
                        'name' => 'it requires this without attribute',
                        'header'=>'Jan',
                        'inputType'=>\kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_SPIN,
                        'options'=>['pluginOptions'=>['min'=>0, 'max'=>5000]],
                        'pluginEvents' => [
                            "editableSuccess"=>"function(event, val, form, data) { console.log(data); }",
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'Feb',
                    'value' => function($model,$key,$idx,$col){
                            //return $model->brand_name;
                            return $model->getMonthBudget(new DateTime('2017-02'), [11311])['budget_net']; // TODO - Testing
                        },
                ],
                [
                    'attribute' => 'Mar',
                    'value' => function($model,$key,$idx,$col){
                            //return $model->brand_name;
                            return $model->getMonthBudget(new DateTime('2017-03'), [11311])['budget_net']; // TODO - Testing
                        },
                ],
```

Comment: hi.display actionIndex in controller.

Comment: Ive added indexAction along with the two grids (including expand row grid template).  The ajax call is made, but its not posting edit column value.

Comment: Will it come in ?   if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')){}

Comment: No.  hasEditable is not being sent..... nor the updated column data.

Comment: have you telegram?send message to  me @amirajloo

Comment: same problem. Did anyone solve it? Thank's